# How do I get the average point value in a raster with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, point

I have a point layer with standard deviation values and i want to get the average value of points in a 1 square-kilometer raster. I used the rasterize tool from QGIS to make a raster but this tool uses only one value of all points that lay in the raster.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Zonal Statistics Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html)

Create polygon layer with a 1x1 km vector grid (Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid) and run the zonal statistics plugin.

It will add serveral attribute to each cell polyogon - like minimal, maximal, median, sum, stdev, ... values of the contained raster cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in the zonal statistics tool i can't select the raster i just made as the rasterlayer and the points as the vector layer. I can only select some layers i made with the rasterize tool and polygons.

Comment: It works now. I used point statistics for polygons in combination with the vector grid. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems like the Vector Grid function is no longer available under the vector research tools menu in QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Zonal Statistics works on a raster layer. The OP was asking how to average vector features ("point layer") using a vector grid. The expected output is a raster, but not the input.